# Can't properly group 14 dates by 7 days in Clickhouse

Tags: sql, clickhouse

I have 14 dates FROM `2023-07-22` TO `2023-08-04`.
I want to Group 14 days by 7 days and as a result I want 2 dates with lates days of these groups.

My query

```sql
SELECT toStartOfInterval(date, toIntervalDay(7)) AS week
FROM
(
  SELECT arrayJoin([toDate('2023-07-22'), toDate('2023-08-04')]) AS date
  ORDER BY date ASC WITH FILL STEP 1
)
GROUP BY week
ORDER BY week ASC
```

Results:

```
┌────────────────week─┐
│ 2023-07-20 00:00:00 │
│ 2023-07-27 00:00:00 │
│ 2023-08-03 00:00:00 │
└─────────────────────┘
```

Why there is 3 rows instead of 2?
From where does this date `2023-07-20 00:00:00` comes from?
And what is wrong with dates?

I expected these values:

```
2023-07-29 00:00:00
2023-08-04 00:00:00
```

**UPD**

Link to Fiddle - https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/87410f62-3031-4a55-9520-bfc5ca11e448

(From Clickhouse Telegram support)

**UPD.2**

Right query for my situation:

```sql
with
    toDate('2023-07-22') as DATE_FROM,
    toDate('2023-08-04') as DATE_TO,
    7 as DAYS_LENGTH,
    DATE_FROM % DAYS_LENGTH as DAYS_SHIFT
select
    date - (date - DAYS_SHIFT) % DAYS_LENGTH as days_group
FROM
(
    SELECT arrayJoin([DATE_FROM, DATE_TO]) AS date
    ORDER BY date ASC WITH FILL STEP 1
)
GROUP BY days_group
order by days_group
format PrettyCompactMonoBlock
;
```

(Thanks for query example to Sergey Churin From Clickhouse Telegram support)

Comment: The question is how the DBMS determines when a seven-day interval starts. If you asked a human to put dates into intervals of seven days, they would ask for details. If I had to put a month's days 1, 7, 11, 14 and 17 into intervals of 7 days, my first idea would be to make two intervals 1-7 and 11-17. But maybe you want consecutive intervals 1-7, 8-14, 14-21 instead. Or you want them to start on a Sunday, so the intervals might be 26-1, 4-11 and 12-18. I don't know why the DBMS chooses interval starting on Thursdays. I think `toStartOfInterval` lacks a proper definition.

Comment: But at least the DBMS comes up with intervals that cover the dates. 2023-07-20 to 2023-07-26, 2023-07-27 to 2023-08-02 and 2023-08-03 to 2023-08-09 are proper seven-day intervals that contain all dates from 2023-07-22 to 2023-08-04.

Comment: What makes you think that to**Start**OfInterval gives you the **end**  and not the **start** of an interval? :-)

Comment: Even if `toStartOfInterval` gives me the start date, why it is not start from `2023-07-22` ?

Comment: Added fiddle link to question.

Comment: Why should a seven-day interval start with 2023-07-22? By what definition? That day is a Saturday. Do you think seven-day intervals should always start with a Saturday? Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `toStartOfInterval(date, toIntervalDay(7))` you want the beginning of a seven-day interval in which the date resides. Who defines that interval? For the day 2023-07-22 it could be any of the seven intervals from `2023-07-16 to 2023-07-22` to `2023-07-22 to 2023-07-28`.

The DBMS has decided that seven-day intervals always start with a Thursday. This may be caused by using a UNIX date representation internally where the first valid day is 1970-01-01. A Thursday.

If you want to put your consecutive days into groups of seven, then just number the rows 0 to n and divide by 7 to get a group number:

```
with
  7 as DAYS_LENGTH
SELECT max(date)
FROM
(  
  SELECT
    date,
    TRUNC((ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY date) - 1) / DAYS_LENGTH) AS grp
  FROM
  (
    SELECT arrayJoin([toDate('2023-07-22'), toDate('2023-08-04')]) AS date
    ORDER BY date ASC WITH FILL STEP 1
  )
)
GROUP BY grp
ORDER BY max(date);
```

Demo: https://fiddle.clickhouse.com/ccb2ca14-104d-4968-bea9-138a075cbd4f

Comment: This is the main key, why my calculations failed!
Added working query for my situation. Thank You!

Comment: Because you are making assumptions. You call a function `toStartOfInterval` with a date and expect it to align its resulting date to the day of 2023-07-20. But the function doesn't even know that date. It makes ranges starting from Thursday, you want it to make ranges starting from a date that you have in mind. This is not how such a function can work. This would require a function that gets two dates, one for the base day, one for the actual day you want to get the calculated day for.